# Function GetNumberFormatEx and GetCurrencyFormatEx link error with WP8 SDK

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I just got a linking problem about these two functions:

- `GetNumberFormatEx`
- `GetCurrencyFormatEx`

Someone had mentioned this problem before, but nobody answered him. Can anybody explain this problem?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/wpdevelop/thread/6973414e-f238-4ebb-9255-6c54ad2d76b6

These two functions are explicitly supported in the MSDN documents, but I can't use them, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dev Center Forum, they offer me the solution. Check this link: [Click to go](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/108ea721-ce45-496c-9731-eb2b1a210325)

All I have to do is adding the `WindowsPhoneGlobalizationUtil.lib` to the project linking setting.